# React Query refetching in react native with useFocusEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-query

I don't want to refetch the query because if the data is not stale it's still refetching it with refetch() function. And also if I add condition like isStale == true then it will refetch but even if I remain on the same screen it will continously refetching it after stale is true

I just want it to work like it works on web useQuery will run on every component render

```
  const { status, isFetching, isPending, isError, isStale, data, error, isFetched, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['brands'],
    queryFn: getBrands,
    staleTime: 10000,
  });

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      console.log(isStale);
      if (isStale === true) {
        refetch();
      }
    }, [isStale]),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong option. If you want the data to refetch after X milliseconds then you should not specify `staleTime: X`. Instead you should be specifying `refetchInterval: X`. In any-case, you don't want the fetching operation tied to your react render cycles.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using useIsFocused hook of react navigation and react query enabled condition. Now the useQuery will not refetch everytime I focus on screen rather just run means if you use staletime and you have fresh data it will not refetch and just display from fresh data

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

const isFocused = useIsFocused();

const { status, isFetching, data, error, isError } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['brands'],
    queryFn: getBrands,
    enabled: isFocused,
    retry: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the useQuery hook to behave more like it does on the web, where it runs on every component render, you can achieve this in React Native by triggering a refetch whenever the component mounts or updates. You can do this by using the useEffect hook instead of useFocusEffect.
Here's how you can modify your code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const { status, isStale, data, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['brands'],
    queryFn: getBrands,
    staleTime: 10000,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === 'success' && isStale) {
      refetch();
    }
  }, [status, isStale, refetch]);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your component CODE */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```